# Models relationship and mapping of models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Warehouse model and an Item Model, simplified to -

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    warehouseCode = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Item(models.Model):
    itemCode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and a third model to map the relationship as whether an item can be stored in a warehouse or not. (locked is the field)

```
class ItemWarehouse(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(ItemMaster)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse)
    locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The system is designed such that before creating any item at least we should have one warehouse.

Now suppose we have 2 warehouses (warehouse_1 and warehouse_2) and we created the First item.
As mentioned above warehouse_1 can have the item First and warehouse_2 is **locked** for item First (No transaction of item First can be done in warehouse_2).

The question is after creating 500 such items (n numbers of items), we created 1 more warehouse called warehouse_3.

What should be the optimized or best way to map the relationship of the newly created warehouse with all the previously created items. Thinking in mind of system design and UI design. I'm using the rest framework and frontend client.

Or a better complete design than what I have till now.

Edit -

During item creation, the system asks for what to do for each warehouse available at that particular time. (item -> each warehouse -> lock or allow)

Comment: Not sure I get the question. If wh3 is newly created it won't have any items in it anyway, so you'd have to add them. If it needs to be locked for any items, you'd add those lock records when you create the warehouse, no?

Comment: @michjnich when wh3 is being created I can't lock or allow (automate the process) for items 1 to 500 because someone needs to decide what to do. For any new item creation after wh3 is created the system asks during item creation. Also providing functionality to allow items (lock or allow) during wh3 creation doesn't seem right. there may be many items.

Comment: OK, gotcha. TBH, this sounds more like a process question than a django question. How did they do this prior to the creation of the system? I'd probably set some kind of "enabled" flag on the new wh though so you could disable it when adding initially then enable it properly once all the locks were added.

Comment: Yes, SADLY this is a process question. More interested in the logic of what can be done to solve this issue.

Comment: prior to the creation of the system ??? paper and mind work, manually they know what not to put where.

Comment: You can't solve a technical problem without knowing what process you are trying to implement. You need to solve the logicistical problem first, then work out how to implement it.

Comment: And you say "manually they know", but how did they keep track of that. What happened when they added a new warehouse? The information needs to come from somewhere - you have to talk to the users and work out the best way for them to handle it rather than trying to make decisions for them.

Comment: @michjnich The information is there I'm only concerned about how to provide this mapping functionality in the system for new whse. I have 2 cases : First - as soon as a new warehouse is created I block all the functionality of the system and tell them to update item 1-500 with wh3 (this particular scenario) in this case they may kill me. Second case - whenever they deal with an item 1-500 on the go after wh3 (created) I provide a pop up to all/block for this item with all new warehouses. Going forward with second or I may be totally wrong.

Comment: Nobody here can help you make this decision - you need to talk to the users and sort out the requirements.